# what's the inverse of this expression (considering it with k's)?

Tags: polynomials, inverse

I've this function:

```
y = 0.01 + x * (0.01 + 19.98 * x)
```

and the inverse of this function seems:

```
x = (sqrt(799200y − 7991) - 1) / 3996
```

Now, what if I need to write using constants instead of 0.01 and 19.98?

Such as write the inverse of this:

```
y = a + x * (a + (b - 2.0 * a) * x)
```

(with a = 0.01 and b = 20.0)

I need a generic inverse function (where I can variate a and b input variable easily).

Comment: to obtain inverse , you can interchange $x$and $y$

Comment: @RamanujanXV nope. if x = 1.0 give to me 20, than using 20 on the same formula doesn't give to me 1.0 :O

Comment: Move everything to one side, expand all the parentheses. You will get a quadratic. Think of $y$ as a constant. You need to find $x$. Note that you might have two roots, one root for a pareticular $y$ value, and no roots for other $y$ values

Comment: @Andrei as said, I need the general formula, not the result given a fixed x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given $y=f(x)$, and you want to get $x=f^{-1}(y)$. To do that, you simplify your last equation to the following form $$\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma-y=0,$$ and you need to find the value of $x$ for any $y$. There are two solutions (sometimes real):
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{-\beta\pm\sqrt{\beta^2-4\alpha(\gamma-y)}}{2\alpha}$$
In your example they chose the solution with $+$.

Comment: it doesn't return correct values. if I try `x = (-b + std::sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * (c - y))) / 2 * a` (with `a = 19.98`, `b = 0.01`, `c = 0.01` and `y = 20`) it should return `1`, not `399.2`...

Comment: That's because you have a small mistake in the implemented formula. Put some parentheses around `2*a`, otherwise you multiply by `a`, not divide. That will give you the right answer

Comment: Correct. Thanks, it seems to work! +1 and accepted!

Comment: If I try 400 as x, it.gives to me wrong result (i.e. 398,408). But seems because in fact your formula is wrong? Found this tool: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+a%2B+x+*+%28a+%2B+%28b+-+a*+2%29+*+x%29 and seems pretty different :(

Comment: Did you try to expand your initial formula to identify the $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ coefficients? I get $\alpha=b-2a$, $\beta=\gamma=a$. Plug these value into my formula, and you get the form given by wolfram

Comment: not sure. Still if I use x=400, a=1 and b=500 and than back, the result is different :(

Comment: With your values I get $y=79680401$ from your equation. Then $\alpha=498$, $\beta=\gamma=1$. The inverse using the $+$ sign is $400$. The one using the negative sign is $-400.0020080321285$

Comment: Here's a c++ snippet: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa510b9830ae4407 . Your formula gives to me 0.892309; than back to original is 398.408 :(

Comment: Like I've mentioned before, $a\ne\alpha$ and so on. So when you call the inverse function use `x=getInversePolyExp(x,min,max-2.0f*min)`